# How often is SQL database in Android app updated

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I am new to working with sql databases with apps.

I created an app that updates an SQL database in real time with information from the user's phone (such as location). The app stops storing this data when the app is stopped. However when I extract the database (by backing up the app files into a tar file using adb back up) , the database file appears to have stopped updating 7 hours **before** I stopped the app and the timestamp for when the file was "last modified" is also 7 hours sooner than what I expected. Looking at the data, the database was updated every second and minute, without gaps up until this point.

I am wondering why the database stopped updating after a certain point even though the app did not stop.

Do sql databases have data/record limits? Is there typically a gap in between when an SQL database is created and when it gets updated?

I create the app in Android Studio. Here is the JAVA code called for updating the table when data is received:

```
//Upgrade Method
    // Lets you drop a tables when there is an update
   @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+myDataTable);

        onCreate(db);

    }


 //Update table Method
    public boolean insertData(final String results1, final String results2) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //create instance of contentvalue
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        //put the column and value information inte contentValues.put() function
        contentValues.put(col1, results1);
        contentValues.put("myData", results2);
        //actually insert the data
        long result = db.insert(myDataTable, null, contentValues);
        if (result==-1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

I'm hoping that you tell me that databases take a hours to update and that if I extract the db file again all the data will be there!!

Comment: where are you calling insertData method?

Comment: do you run a service to make the insertData method ?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question right and from my knowledge, There is no time lag in-between you writing data into the sqlite db using some method provided by Android like

```
db.insert(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values);
```

and the data getting reflected in the table. There should have been an error while the data was inserted. do check for the return value of you insert function. if it has returned -1 then there is an error in insertion.